# Get integer row-index in dataframe where column matches specific value

Tags: python, pandas, select, dataframe, indexing

Given a Pandas dataframe, where one of the columns looks like this:

```
Date
2016-04-15
2016-04-14
2016-04-13
2016-04-12 
2016-04-11
2016-04-08
```

How do I get the row-index of a particular value assuming that values are unique?

For example, "2016-04-13" would return 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `df.index.get_loc('2016-04-14')` to get the integer location for requested label. This will return `1` as intital starts from `0`. So you can add one to get the index value as `2`

Comment: Not very Pythonic. @ayhan's is. Probably more performant too.

Answer (score 6):

With boolean indexing, you can slice the dataframe to get only the rows where the date equals "2016-04-13" and get the index of the slice:

```
df[df.Date == "2016-04-13"].index
Out[37]: Int64Index([2], dtype='int64')
```

With the uniqueness assumption, there will be only one element in that array, so you can take the 0th element:

```
df[df.Date == "2016-04-13"].index[0]
Out[38]: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`df['Date'].values.tolist().index("2016-04-13")` will return 2