# how to find data from dataFrame at a time,when the condition is a list

Tags: python, pandas

as i have the data frame as follow

```
In [107]: xx
Out[107]:
   1         2         3         4
0  0 -1.234881  0.039231 -0.399870
1  1 -1.761733 -1.186537  0.043678
2  2  0.707564 -0.270639 -0.251519
3  3 -0.979584  0.476025 -1.587889
4  4 -0.576429  1.987681 -0.322581
5  5 -0.695509  1.285029  0.393906
6  6 -0.036627 -0.380702 -0.170813
7  7  0.673423  0.860289 -0.774651
8  8 -1.000333  0.978760  0.256645
9  9 -0.446005 -0.584627  0.187244
```

and the condition is the value of `column = 1` just as

```
con = [2,4,6,8]
```

is there any function I can use, the I can get the result like follow:

```
   1         2         3         4
2  2  0.707564 -0.270639 -0.251519
4  4 -0.576429  1.987681 -0.322581
6  6 -0.036627 -0.380702 -0.170813
8  8 -1.000333  0.978760  0.256645
```

thanks!

Comment: Did you have a look at the following posts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661701/how-to-drop-a-list-of-rows-from-pandas-dataframe   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502298/python-pandas-get-index-from-column-value

Comment: Seems like column one is just the same as the index ... Is it ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `.isin()` method:

```
con = [2,4,6,8]
xxx[xxx["1"].isin(con)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `isin`

```
In [29]: df[df['1'].isin(con)]
Out[29]:
   1         2         3         4
2  2  0.707564 -0.270639 -0.251519
4  4 -0.576429  1.987681 -0.322581
6  6 -0.036627 -0.380702 -0.170813
8  8 -1.000333  0.978760  0.256645
```